# Number of independent elements in transforming metric to be locally flat

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, linear-algebra

I am currently reading through "Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell" and I'm stuck with two questions on a derivation in Chapter 1.6, Curved Spacetime: Gauss and Riemann. The section concerns a proof that for any sufficiently smooth space of dimension N, we can choose a neighborhood such that it is locally flat ($g_{\mu \nu} = \delta_{\mu \nu}$).

After a few steps, Zee reports that $g'_{\lambda \sigma}(0) = g_{\mu \nu}(0)K^{\mu}_{\lambda}K^{\nu}_{\sigma}$ ($K^{\nu}_{\sigma}$ being just some coefficient) or in matrix form $g' = K^TgK$. As $g$ is symmetric and real,

> "...there always exists a matrix $K$ that will diagonalize it... we could scale each coordinate one by one by an appropriate factor, so that the diagonal elements become 1."

What I understand from this is that we ultimately can have $K = P\tilde{D}$, where:

- $P$ is the matrix that diagonalized $g$, i.e. $D = P^TgP$ (with $P^TP = I$)
- $\tilde{D}_{ii} = 1/\sqrt{D_{ii}}$

This means that $K^TgK = \tilde{D}^TP^TgP\tilde{D} = \tilde{D}D\tilde{D} = I$.

**1. My first question is if my thinking is correct?**

He then goes on to count the number of independent elements in $K$ to show that it is just a rotation. This is because

> "$g_{\mu \nu}(0)$ has $\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$ arbitrary elements to begin with we had to use this many elements in $K^{\mu}_{\nu}$ to adjust these to $\delta_{\mu \nu}$. Hence, the object $K^{\mu}_{\nu}$ has $N^2-\frac{1}{2}N(N+1) = \frac{1}{2}N(N-1)$ elements left over."

**2. I'm struggling with this first sentence, as I don't see how one follows from the other.**

I mean, I can understand given $P$ is orthogonal, then there are $\frac{1}{2}N(N-1)$ independent elements in it, and $\tilde{D}$ has no independent elements then $K =  P\tilde{D}$ has $\frac{1}{2}N(N-1)$ independent elements. The first sentence in the above quote seems to mean that for any matrix with the restriction of having $\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$ independent elements then we would need exactly that to transform it to $I$, which is not intuitive to me. Am I missing something here?